# Construct a function call from arguments within a function

Tags: r

Let's say I have a function like this:

```
myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    if(arg3 == 'A') funA(arg1, arg2)
    else if(arg3 == 'B') funB(arg1, arg2)
    else if(arg3 == 'C') funC(arg1, arg2)

}
```

Is there a way to not continually repeat `arg1, arg2`, but somehow construct the call more intelligently? I was looking into `match.call` but am not sure if it fits my use case.

Comment: Or maybe `myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) get(paste0("fun", arg3))(arg1, arg2)` but I'm not sure whether your functions connect as in your example.

Comment: @shayaa how do I accept your comment as the best answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `match.arg()` along with `paste0()`.

```
myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    stopifnot(arg3 %in% c("A", "B", "C"))
    paste0("fun", arg3)
}
```

This will trigger an error if `arg3` is not in the choices `c("A", "B", "C")`

```
myFun(arg3 = "A")
# [1] "funA"
myFun(arg3 = "defg")
# Error: arg3 %in% c("A", "B", "C") is not TRUE
```

So we can just use that in `do.call()` to call it with the other arguments.

```
myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    stopifnot(arg3 %in% c("A", "B", "C"))
    do.call(paste0("fun", arg3), list(arg1, arg2))
}
```

Comment: Is there a clean way to check if arg3 is an accepted value? I.E. if arg3 = 'dafjgadf' what will happen?

Comment: @FrankP. - I revamped the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Can your functions actually be pasted together or is that just an effect of the example? If so, consider this:

```
get(paste0("me", "an"))(1:5)
[1] 3
```

I created the function by pasting its name together. So in your example:

```
myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3) {

get(paste0("fun", arg3))(arg1, arg2)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `switch`

```
myFun <- function(arg1, arg2, arg3){
    switch(arg3, 
        A = {
         out <- funA(arg1, arg2)
        },
       B = {
         out <- funB(arg1, arg2)
       },
       C= {
         out <- funC(arg1, arg2)
      },
     stop("Enter something that makes sense!")
   )
  return(out)
}

funA <- function(x,y) mean(c(x,y))
funB <- function(x,y) sum(c(x,y))
funC <- function(x,y) var(c(x,y))

myFun(3, 4, "A")
#[1] 3.5
myFun(3, 4, "B")
#[1] 7
myFun(3, 4, "C")
#[1] 0.5
myFun(3, 4, "D")
```

> Error in myFun(3, 4, "D") : Enter something that makes sense!